# Subaru Forester 2008

Tags: automatic-transmission, subaru

Just had the transmission changed and all the lights are on ABS Cruise check engine light oil temp flashing when I start the car there is code p0732 p o 763 and PO700 do I need to have this reprogrammed or is there a problem in the new transmission question

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Take it back to the shop who replaced the transmission and have them fix what they messed up or didn't do. They should have given back to you in the shape you expected upon delivery. If there was something which needed to be done as far as updating or reflashing, it should have been included with the transmission replacement.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a transmission related issue. This is an issue that one should not find on a new transmission.

P0700 code indicates low or dirty transmission fluid, faulty wiring, or a dirty or defective TCM (Transmission Control Module).

P0763 code indicates a shifting solenoid issue.

P0732 code indicate Gear 2 incorrect  ratio. Commonly seen in automatic transmissions.

This last code is triggered when input shaft data versus the output shaft data doesn't correspond to what ECM/PCM expect in 2nd gear.

Comment: How do I fix it?